# Cucumber step for all scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have around 30 scenarios that all bar one require this step to be at the top of the `Background`:

```
Given I have an account:
  | name     | path     |
  | ticketee | ticketee |
```

For the one that doesn't require this step it is not important that it exists or doesn't exist, because it's the feature for creating accounts. I can simply use a different account name and path for this.

Now, I was thinking rather than putting this in every single feature file 29 times that I could make use of the `Before` method in Cucumber which would mean placing a file in `features/support/create_account.rb` which would have this code:

```
Before do
  steps(%Q{
    Given I have an account:
      | name     | path     |
      | ticketee | ticketee |
  })
end
```

The only downside from this is that it extracts what some would think belongs in the feature to a very difficult-to-track-down location and is probably not standard. But on the other hand, it saves quite a lot of repetition.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a [tagged hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) such as `@with_ticketee_account`. It still brings a bit of repetition, but it makes the background of the scenario more obvious than having it completely hidden.

If you wanted to make it so you only have to tag the one odd scenario, maybe create a tagged hook such as `@without_ticketee_account` which sets a variable which your generic before filter could check for before creating the ticketee account.

Comment: Never thought of using a tagged hook for this, that would work out fine!

Answer (score 1):

Tagged hook is IMHO a good idea.

Another Idea is to make that one line instead of three. perhaps:

```
Given I have an account called "ticketee"
```

which does all the same stuff, but is succinct as well. I have never used those tables with cucumber because I can usually make stuff on one line that reads better.

Comment: I'm using this for Rails 3 in Action and the lines of code can't extend past 72 characters in length. Tables are also preferred because it's very easy to add additional information to them without drastically changing the step.

Comment: just reduce the amount of info that you give, and increase the amount that is implied... but yeah, long lines do become a problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd go ahead and extract it into the Before block like you have proposed or use a factory (e. g. factory_girl).